# RestController not working in oauth2 Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have setup a auth server and resource server as mentioned in the below article
http://www.hascode.com/2016/03/setting-up-an-oauth2-authorization-server-and-resource-provider-with-spring-boot/

I downloaded the code and it is working fine. Now the issue is that in the resource provider project there is only one RestController annotated class as shown below

```
package com.hascode.tutorial;

import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableResourceServer
public class SampleResourceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleResourceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String securedCall() {
        return "success (id: " + UUID.randomUUID().toString().toUpperCase() + ")";
    }
}
```

Now when I create a different class annotated with **@RestController** as shown below

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/public")
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepo;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/person", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Person>> getPeople() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(personRepo.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Person> getPerson(@PathVariable long id) {
        Person person = personRepo.findOne(id);

        if (person != null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(personRepo.findOne(id), HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> addPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(personRepo.save(person), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deletePerson(@PathVariable long id, Principal principal) {
        Person currentPerson = personRepo.findByUsername(principal.getName());

        if (currentPerson.getId() == id) {
            personRepo.delete(id);
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/parties", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Party>> getPersonParties(@PathVariable long id) {
        Person person = personRepo.findOne(id);

        if (person != null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(person.getParties(), HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }

}
```

but when I tried to access the service (http://localhost:9001/resources/public/person) I am getting 404

```
{
    "timestamp": 1508752923085,
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/resources/public/person"
}
```

when I access http://localhost:9001/resources/ I am getting the correct result like

**success (id: 27DCEF5E-AF11-4355-88C5-150F804563D0)**

Should I register the Contoller anywherer or am I missing any configuration

https://bitbucket.org/hascode/spring-oauth2-example

**UPDATE 1**

**ResourceServerConfiguration.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration  extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .anonymous().and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/resources/public/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/resources/private/**").authenticated();
    }
}
```

**OAuth2SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .anonymous().and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/resources/public/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/resources/private/**").authenticated();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/resources/public/**").permitAll() //Allow register url
         .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
         .antMatcher("/resources/**").authorizeRequests() //Authenticate all urls with this body /api/home, /api/gallery
         .antMatchers("/resources/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
         .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler()); //This is optional if you want to handle exception
    }
```

Comment: In you main class replace `@EnableResourceServer` with `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. let me known the status. Also make sure that you make a `get` request to server instead of `post`.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna now atleast status changed from 404 to 401, but now I am not able to authenticate .....I am getting 401 `Full authentication is required to access this resource` even though I have the given the right access token. `@EnableResourceServer` is for making it as resource server for oauth right

Comment: I think something is wrong in spring configuration. Did you use spring security here? If answer is yes then please put your `HttpSecurity` config in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`

Comment: I am using `spring-cloud-starter-security`.  this is my pom.xml  https://bitbucket.org/hascode/spring-oauth2-example/src/58bbb747d2d28501a55b678382e12d7b1d8ab9e5/resource-provider/pom.xml?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: I see your `pom.xml`. Here you include `spring-security`. Put your spring security configuration. Did you get my point ?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna Yes...I have added those configuration, Can you check my Update 1. but still I am getting 401

Comment: I believe your new `@RestController` is not picked up by Spring boot. Check if the controller is available to be scanned by Spring boot. Also if you put your new controller in the same package as your `@SpringBootApplication` it should work.

Comment: In your `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` use `.antMatchers("/resources/public/**", "/resources/private/**").permitAll().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler())` and let me know the status.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan Yes when I move to the same package spring boots is able to scan those controller but still getting 401

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna I have added those changes still the same ....getting 401

Comment: @AbdullahKhan is there any way in which we can explicitly mention another package where other controllers are residing in spring boots

Comment: @ComponentScan  might help you.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan I have put `@ComponentScan` in `PersonController`  still getting 404

Comment: @AbdullahKhan `@ComponentScan` worked....

Comment: @AbdullahKhan how can we make api's under `/resources/public/` guest enabled (can access without authentication) and apis under `/resources/private/` protected (cannot access without authentication)

Comment: i am posting an answer please check that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your new controller `PersonController` *discoverable* by Spring Boot either by using [`@ComponentScan`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) on a configuration class or by moving `PersonController` to a package *in* or *under* your main class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`.

Second fix your `OAuth2SecurityConfiguration` class like so

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .anonymous().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll(); //This will permit the (oauth/token) url for getting access token from the oauthserver.
    }        

}
```

Now fix your resource server like so

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration  extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/v1/register", "/api/v1/publicOne", "/api/v1/publicTwo").permitAll() //Allow urls
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .antMatcher("/api/**").authorizeRequests() //Authenticate all urls with this body /api/home, /api/gallery
            .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler()); //This is optional if you want to handle exception
    }
}
```

Find the complete source code [here](https://github.com/Abdullah8006/myapp-oracle/tree/oauth-with-database-token-store). Hope this helps.

**Note:** You can customize your urls based on the above answer.

Comment: I have added the ResourceServerConfiguration   configuration with reference from yours, but still I am not able to access apis under `public` without authentication. It is giving me like this `{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}`

Comment: can u check my UPDATE 2

Comment: Thats because now you need access tokens to access all the secured urls.

Comment: Actually I want those apis that comes under public should need to be open without authentication, In oauth2 can we do that....I am pretty new to this one...

Comment: That defeats the whole purpose of Oauth. Anyway check the updated `@EnableResourceServer`.

Comment: what does that `publicOne` and `publicTwo` means...can those be access without authentication

Comment: Thats just to show you how to exclude urls from being oauth verified. Your can exclude the urls that way but also you need to have a @RequestMapping to those urls in any of your controller class.

Comment: can we do something with `@Override
 public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
  web.ignoring().antMatchers("/public/**");
 }`

Comment: Yes checkout [this](https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/#customwebsecurityconfigureradapter).

Comment: Any Idea on this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46911525/uncategorized-exception-occured-during-ldap-processing-nested-exception-is-java

Answer (score 1):

Why your request url is **http://localhost:9001/resources/public/person**

I think it should be like **http://localhost:9001/public/person**

Comment: no actually I am defining the contextPath (`/resources`) in my properties file `server.contextPath: /resources`

Comment: "O" sorry.
I missed that.
It would better if your share your whole preject.

Comment: you can get the complete project from https://bitbucket.org/hascode/spring-oauth2-example/src , in addition add a dummy rest controller and the configuration shown in my question updates

Comment: add a dummy controller in the project and try to access that

Comment: The project sample you followed is not enough. I hope this url will help you to understand.

https://github.com/dynamind/spring-boot-security-oauth2-minimal