# Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, ldap

I am trying to authenticate using LDAP in oauth2 with spring boot security. My configuration is as given below

```
@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class LdapConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static String url ="ldap://myldapdomain.com:389/OU=Users,OU=Accounts,DC=myldapdomain,DC=com";

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();

    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .userSearchFilter("(uid={0})")
            .contextSource().url(url);
        }
    }
}
```

When I tried to login to **http://localhost:9000/api/oauth/token** with the required LDAP userid and password I am getting the following exception

```
{
    "timestamp": 1508848799342,
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090749, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v2580\u0000]; remaining name '/'",
    "path": "/api/oauth/token"
}
```

Can anyone please help me on this

**UPDATE 1**

I have created a java standalone application for LDAP authentication using the below code `authenticateUser` function. There I am able to login successfully

```
private String ldapURL = "ldap://myldapdomain:389";

private String ldapDomain = "myldapdomain.com";


public void authenticateUser(String username, String password) throws NamingException {
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapURL);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username + "@" + ldapDomain);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

        DirContext context = null;
        try {
            context = new InitialDirContext(env);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (context != null) {
                context.close();
            }
            System.out.println("LDAP auth Failed:::"+ e.getMessage());
            //throw new LoginFailedException("Invalid User Id orPassword");
        }
}
```

Comment: Will [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975309/spring-security-ad-ldap-error-code-1-000004dc-ldaperr-dsid-0c0906e8) help?

Comment: @xiaofeng.li not getting much what exactly the problem is

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a `managerDn` which is used to bind to your LDAP.

E.g. `ldapAuthentication().contextSource()
                    .url(securityConfigProperties.getUrl())
                    .port(securityConfigProperties.getPort())
                    .managerDn(securityConfigProperties.getManagerDn()).managerPassword(securityConfigProperties.getManagerPassword())`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what is `managerDn`, actually I am trying to allow users to authenticate directly to ldap server

Comment: From JavaDocs: Username (DN) of the "manager" user identity (i.e. "uid=admin,ou=system") which will be used to authenticate to a (non-embedded) LDAP server. If omitted, anonymous access will be used.

Comment: Can you check my `Update 1`. when I try to authenticate using that code, I am able to login successfully using the userid and password. There I am not using any `mangerDn` or `managerPassword`

Comment: The `managerDN` is used by OpenLDAP itself. Applications and persons should not use it. Instead, users with the appropriate access should be defined in the DIT.